# Media player sound not working, works fine in browsers

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, vlc, browser

I've been trying to figure out how to properly record sound with a program and was messing with various settings, but now I have screwed something up royally. I no longer can get sound using media player applications, whether it be VLC or something else. I get it fine on firefox and chrome. (edit: actually, it totally depends on the site. Youtube doesn't work.)

I've already tried everything in this guide:

https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

The only effect is seemed to have is that now in the top-right there is no longer any audio icon.

Maybe helpful as a clue: Adjusting the normal Ubuntu volume bar no longer affects the volume of the sound in firefox at all.

Any help would be really nice. I'm in 16.04.

Comment: To enable sound volume again, install [unity-tweak-tool](https://www.lifewire.com/customize-ubuntu-unity-tweak-tool-2202104) and check voluym option at Panel tab. Install `pavucontrol`to verify which sound profiles are receiving audio.

Comment: Audio interne Stéréo numérique (IEC958) is working it seems, when I play a file the bar shows activity, but that's the audio device I have selected in VLC and I still don't hear anything.

Comment: Did you installed `pavucontrol`? Open, go to playback tab and see if there's a gauge for VLC at there. Maybe it's muted. [Look at my pavucontrol](https://imgur.com/t44fl46), VLC is playing right now. I use this sound device.

Comment: Yeah, pavucontrol I already have, this is what mine looks like: 

https://imgur.com/a/C7u6I

I made sure it wasn't muted.

Comment: Edit: I fixed it! I changed the sound exit device in Ubuntu settings and it worked, which is weird because I could have sworn I had tried that before already. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You welcome! Post your own answer, detailing every steps you took.

Answer (score 0):

It suffised to go into Ubuntu sound settings and change the exit device to Analog headphones - Internal audio. Pretty obvious solution, thought I had already tried, apparently not.